# How can I add a anchor tag in xml data passed to javascript for google maps api

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps

I am using google maps api, I am pulling the marker data from data.php -

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
<markers>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locations";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $lat = $row['lat'];
      $lng = $row['lng'];
      $name= $row['name'];
      $address = $row['address'];

      echo "<marker id='".$id."' name='<a href='site.php'>'".$name."'</a>' address='".$address."' lat='".$lat."' lng='".$lng."' type='X'/>";
}
}
?>
</markers>
```

In the main.php file I am loading the map and markers from data.php -

```
 downloadUrl('data.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

When I add the anchor tag it doesn't load the markers anymore I get Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null, what can I do to pass a anchor tag here?

Comment: I would strongly advise that you use `DOMDocument` to generate the XML rather than manually doing so with strings - or do away with XML and use json as it is lighter and easier to process clientside. The problem I think lies in the use of single quotes within the string and the lack of escaping thereof. Certainly using DOMDocument is more verbose in the code you need to write but it should prove robust enough to generate valid XML when a simple misuse of quotes renders the above invalid.

Comment: One thing I can tell you is that your echo line is wrong. The `name` attribute your echoing is invalid. You cannot start an attribute with a single quote and then embed a single quote within that attribute without escaping the inner single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my method from adding the link in the xml data to the js script

```
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          var linkText = document.createTextNode(name);
          a.appendChild(linkText);
          a.title = name;
          a.href = "http://example?id=" + name;
          infowincontent.appendChild(a);
```